# How to use string formatting specification to control decimals using inputs

Tags: python, format

I was wondering why there is an error using a variable inside of the f statement and how I could fix it.

The code:

```
from math import *
precision = float(input("Enter digits of decimals:"))
print(f'The value of pi to {precision} digits is: {pi:.{precision}f}')
```

And the error:

```
    print(f'The value of pi to {precision} digits is: {pi:.{precision}f}')
ValueError: Invalid format specifier
```

Comment: Use an `int` instead of a `float` for the precision, you can't pass a float for this option

Answer (score 1):

Precision cannot be `float`, needs to be `int`

```
from math import *
precision = int(input("Enter digits of decimals:"))
print(f'The value of pi to {precision} digits is: {pi:.{precision}f}')
```